# Alternating values when creating dataframe

Tags: r

```
agent1 <- data.frame (agentNo =1,
                      state = "e",
                      mixing = runif(1,0,1))

nPop1 <- 10

#Create a population of agents#
for (k in 1:nTime1){
  for (i in 1:TamanhoMercado){
    agent2 <- data.frame( agentNo = i,
                          state = c("S","E"),
                          mixing = runif(1,0,1))
    
    agent1 <- rbind (agent1, agent2)
  }
}
```

When i do that, i get

2-s

2-e

3-s

3-e

4-s

5-e and so on

i want it to be
1-s
2-e
3-s
4-e
and have the mixing also be different value
how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something as simple as the following?

```
nPop1 = 20
agents = data.frame(agentNo = seq(nPop1),
                    state = rep(c("s","e"),nPop1/2),
                    mixing = runif(nPop1)
)
```